# How to trigger a <p:ajax event inside a c:forEach?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I need to trigger an ajax event that is inside a panel and the panel is inside a c:forEach, how can I do this? The way I tried to do it and put the example, it does not fire the event in the bean.

This is the xhtml:

```
<p:panel header="Configuração de Dashboard">
            <p:dashboard id="dashBoardConfigurado" model="#{gerDashboardBean.dashboard.model}">
                <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{gerDashboardBean.doOrdenacao}" update=":form1:mensagem" />
                <c:forEach var="pn" items="#{gerDashboardBean.dashboard.children}">
                    <p:panel id="#{pn.id}" closable="true">
                        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{gerDashboardBean.fecharPainel}" update=":form1:mensagem :form1:dashBoardConfigurado" />
                    </p:panel>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:dashboard>
        </p:panel>
```

This is the event:

```
public void fecharPainel(CloseEvent event) {
    for (UIComponent pn : this.dashboard.getChildren()) {
        if (pn.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getComponent().getId())) {
            this.dashboard.getChildren().remove(pn);
            for (String widget : this.coluna1.getWidgets()) {
                if (widget.equalsIgnoreCase(pn.getId())) {
                    this.coluna1.removeWidget(widget);
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (String widget : this.coluna2.getWidgets()) {
                if (widget.equalsIgnoreCase(pn.getId())) {
                    this.coluna2.removeWidget(widget);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JsfUtil.warn("Painel removido com sucesso");
}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the close button? I'm trying to reproduce but the close button doesn't get rendered inside c:forEach

Comment: This code is working for me right now, with the same listener you posted here:  <c:forEach id="comments" items="#{caseView.comments}" var="c" varStatus="myVarStatus">
                    <p:panel id="eventor" header="eventor" closable="true" toggleable="false">
                        <p:outputLabel value="eventor panel"></p:outputLabel>
                        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{caseView.eventor}" />
                    </p:panel>
                  </c:forEach>